# setcookie is not Working by jQuery call in php

Tags: php, jquery, cookies

I try to setcookie using jquery and php. Please see my code below

In my jquery file, i written the following code

```
function mycookie(cookieObj) {
        
        $.post(
         'cookieObj.php',
             {
                 method : 'set',
                 cookieObj  : cookieObj
             }, 
             function success(data) {
                console.log(data);
            }
        ); 
        
    }
```

And in **cookieObj.php**

```
<?php
if ('set' === $_POST['method'] && !empty($_POST['cookieObj'])) {
    setcookie('my_cookie', $_POST['cookieObj'], time() + (86400 * 30), "/");
    $my_cookie = $_COOKIE['my_cookie'];
    Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
    die(json_encode($my_cookie)); 
}
?>
```

But here **console.log(data)**; is return null. Please help to solve this.

After setting the value then I want to take the value using following function

```
function getcookie(){
        
        $.post(
         'cookieObj.php',,
             {
                 method : 'get',
             },
             function success(data) {
                console.log(data);
              
             }
        ); 

    }
```

And in **cookieObj.php**

```
if ('get' === $_POST['method']) {
     $my_cookie = $_COOKIE['my_cookie'];
     Header('Content-Type: application/json;charset=utf8');
     echo json_encode($my_cookie); 
}
```

Please help to correct both functions.

Comment: As it says in [the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php): _"**Cookies will not become visible until the next loading of a page that the cookie should be visible for.** To test if a cookie was successfully set, check for the cookie on a next loading page before the cookie expires. Expire time is set via the expires_or_options parameter. A nice way to debug the existence of cookies is by simply calling print_r($_COOKIE);."_

Comment: thats true, but when i refresh page also null is showing

Comment: `$.post('cookieObj.php',, {...` - probably not intentional, that you are passing _nothing_ for the second parameter here.

Comment: Not sure about this, but it might be that the client needs to be refreshed before it reads and sends the cookie to the backend (since the cookie lives in the client)? Do you have an actual case you can show? The code you've posted makes little sense imho, since you could just set the cookie in JS directly without involving the server at all.